# Top Center and Bottom View in React Native with styled components

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I'm trying to make a layout an I have 3 `Views` that I want to align one in the top, center and bottom.

[image]

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    return (
        <MainView>
            <TopView>
            </TopView>

            <CenterView>
            </CenterView>

            <BottomView>
            </BottomView>
        </MainView>
    )
}
```

What styles should I add to each `View`?

I have tried so many combinations of `text-align-vertical` and `justify-content` but I couldn't figure it out how it works.

I'm using `styled-components` but even in normal style is good for me.

Comment: Is there any height limitation for any of the view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `justifyContent: 'space-between'` to the `MainView`.

Here is a snack of an example. You will need to convert the styles to Styled-Components.

https://snack.expo.io/BJ4wFLcWr

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.view}></View>
        <View style={styles.view}></View>
        <View style={styles.view}></View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  view: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 100,
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderColor: '#000',
  }
});
```